# How to convert date format in angular bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular date picker. When user selects a date, I want to filter results.

I've added ng-change to the date picker and it is detecting a change and passing the date value. But the format is not correct.

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected('{{dt}}')" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></uib-datepicker>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.dateSelected = function(passedDate){
    console.log('Date Selected ' + passedDate);
}
```

This gives

```
2016-04-26T12:18:56.794Z
```

How do I convert it to

```
18 March, 2016
```

or something similar.

I'tried a couple of option by updating $scope.options based on the documentation, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The html should be like this you don't need {{}} inside ng-change

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected(dt)" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></uib-datepicker>

var monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April",....];
```

And JS should be like

```
console.log($scope.dt.getDate()+', '+monthArray[$scope.dt.getMonth()]+', '+$scope.dt.getFullYear());
```

Comment: this does not work, when I replace newDate with passedDate, it gives error passedDate.getMonth is not a function

Comment: edited my answer try to use $scope.dt. getMonth instead of using passedDate.getMonth

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker in html

```
 <div class="input-group ui-datepicker">
                                <input type="text"
                                       class="form-control date"
                                       datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                                       ng-model="dt"
                                       is-open="opened"
                                       min-date="minDate"
                                       max="'2015-06-22'"
                                       ng-readonly="true"
                                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                       date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                                       ng-required="true"
                                       close-text="Close" style="cursor:auto;">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
```

Set a format as :

```
 $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

 $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };
```

Comment: HTML is like this -  <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected('{{dt}}')" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></uib-datepicker>

Comment: Irrespective of the HTML, the date format is similar on how to be used. You have the same model and method to change format